# Signing/verification between Java and the OpenSSL

Tags: rsa, signature, padding

I'm trying to sign/verify data between a C application and a Java application.

In java for now I was using the built-in JCE provider with `SHA256withRSA` as algorithm. On the C part I'm using OpenSSL `RSA_sign`/`RSA_verify` methods with `NID_sha256` as type.

With this configuration I can't verify in my java application data signed from the C one and vice versa. It seems that `SHA256withRSA` is using PKCS#1 v1.5 and openssl state that they use PKCS# 2.0 as padding ([source](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_sign.html)).

This is why I think that the problem could come from this padding difference, but I can't find any JCE provider that support the v2.0 padding.

Is this correct? What is the difference between these paddings?

Comment: I edited your question to ask a slightly different question that the answer below answers. This is because the original question was in my opinion off topic as it was a programming problem to be solved. If you disagree, you can roll back my edit.

Comment: No, you are right, this is a good edit !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with the signature scheme, something else is wrong.

RSA is specified by the RSA cryptography standard, PKCS#1 (mirrored in various RFC's). The PKCS#1 v1.5 padding was introduced in version 1.5 but it persisted in 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2. Those did however introduce a more secure padding scheme called PSS.

Unfortunately nobody calls the signature generation schemes by their true name: [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-32). Both your C code and your Java code seem to use that signature scheme.

Comment: You can post code to stackoverflow so the crypto guys there can check what goes wrong, if possible with test material (keys, input & signature values).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find anywhere in wich version PSS was introduces so I thaught it could be in 2.0 since it's a major version.
I'll try to investigate a little more and if I didn't find anything I follow your advice !

Comment: @darkheir PKCS#1v2.0 adds OAEP for encryption and v2.1 adds PSS for signature; details are in http://http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447 . But that API in OpenSSL (RSA_sign/verify) only does original 'type 1' padding, now retronymed RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 as Maarten says. (*Other* APIs support more paddings, though for compability both v1.5 schemes, type 1 and type 2, are named simply 'pkcs1' which can be confusing.) In Java, SunRsaSign supports only v1.5 padding, although you can add BouncyCastle to get PSS. I concur your problem is something else.

Comment: Yeah you were right,  I checked with the developer in charge of the C part and he had to correct some stuff. Now everything is working well!

Comment: @darkheir As long as it's working...I hope I helped a bit by excluding the signature scheme.